# Shadow is perfect on iphone but on ipad its just become very short

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview

[image]

this is screen shot from iphone here shadow is perfectly fine but when i run app on ipad its become like this..

[image]

now this is the problem i want it to be like 1st image on ipad also..

i am using this code to drop shadow

```
extension UIView {

    // OUTPUT 1
    func dropShadow(scale: Bool = true) {
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = 0.5
        layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: -1, height: 1)
        layer.shadowRadius = 1
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: bounds).cgPath
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
        layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
    }

    // OUTPUT 2
    func dropShadow(color: UIColor, opacity: Float = 0.5, offSet: CGSize, radius: CGFloat = 1, scale: Bool = true) {
        layer.masksToBounds = false
        layer.shadowColor = color.cgColor
        layer.shadowOpacity = opacity
        layer.shadowOffset = offSet
        layer.shadowRadius = radius
        layer.shadowPath = UIBezierPath(rect: self.bounds).cgPath
        layer.shouldRasterize = true
        layer.rasterizationScale = scale ? UIScreen.main.scale : 1
    }
}
```

using this line to drop shadow on any view

```
shadowView.dropShadow(color: .black, opacity: 0.7, offSet: CGSize(width: -1, height: 1), radius: 5, scale: true)
```

anyone know where the problem is.??

thanks in advance :)

Comment: can u show frame of the views with the shadow

Comment: didnt give frame.. i user autolayout. 
view is in tableviews cell having leading = 8, traling = 8 , top = 8 and bottom = 8 from content view of cell

Comment: have you tried to move your code into did layoutsubviews?(dont forget to call super.didlayoutsubviews() )

Comment: @roozbehmo no i didnt try that

Comment: where u run shadowView.dropShadow

Comment: try that if you can because seems like your path is created before the view has been properly layout yet

Comment: thanks alot @roozbehmo its work like charm thankks brooo... :)

Comment: of course is it ok if i put this as an answer?

Comment: give this as answer so i can give you thumbs upp ;)

Comment: @roozbehmo yesss for sure...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you are using the bounds value when the view hasn't been properly layout yet.

Set the shadow in viewDidLayoutSubviews. don't forget to call `super.didlayoutsubviews()`

or you can call

```
view.layoutIfNeeded()
```